# Python error [WinError 123] (File name, directory name or volume label syntax incorrect) when using __file__

Tags: python

I've been writing a program which writes to text files in the directory it's placed in. So, to find the path to the directory it is placed in, I used this statement:

```
currentpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

But whenever I call the program **outside of Idle** it gives the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I have no idea why this is happening, and even less why it happens outside of Idle and not inside.

So please can someone help because I have little hope of solving this on my own.

*Oh, and PS. The name of the file is "File sprayer.py" and the directory name is "File sprayer test". I'm not sure if that helps.*

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of Idle"?

Comment: I mean when I run from the command line or from double-clicking in Windows Explorer rather than using the Run>Run Module feature of Idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this?

```
currentpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life saver